# EF code first - Cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, database-design, ef-code-first

I'm making a voting system. A `Poll` can have any number of `PollOption`s. A `Vote` can be blank (null on `PollOptionId`).

My models:

```
public class Poll
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<PollOption> Options { get; set; }
    // Some more properties.
}

public class PollOption
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PollId { get; set; }
    public Poll Poll { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    // Some more properties.
}

public class Vote
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PollId { get; set; } // Needed for blank votes
    public Poll Poll { get; set; }
    public Guid? PollOptionId { get; set; } // Null if blank vote
    public PollOption Option { get; set; }
    // Some more properties.
}
```

Upon migration, I am faced with the error message

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Votes_Polls_PollId' on table 'Votes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I can see the cycle, but I'm not sure how I could make my models any different for my purpose.

Could the design be changed to avoid the need to add a ON DELETE NO ACTION in modelBuilder?

If not, how would I do it?

My attempt:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Poll)
    .WithMany(o => o.Options)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

... which of course is not working, because `PollOption != Vote`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add Votes to Poll

```
public class Poll
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PollOption> Options { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Vote> Votes{ get; set; } 
    // Some more properties.
}
```

and maybe it would be usefull to make PollId nullable too

```
public class Vote
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    .....
    public Guid? PollId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Poll Poll { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. What is the point of having `PollId` nullable?

Comment: You are very welcome! It is optional. I was not sure that to add votes would be enough.